# How can I batch process using Paulstretch for Mac?

Tags: software, processing, batch-processing, batch, time-stretching

I'm working on a really big project at the moment and I've been experimenting with Paulstretch to create sound beds with some of my recordings. I love the way it smears the transients of the audio files and brings out some of the pure tonal elements, great for adding layers of texture to my sounds.

The problem I have is that with the huge number of files I'm dealing with it's going to take too long for me to individually process each file that I need, especially considering the way that the Paulstretch GUI operates. I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions for creating some sort of batch process for Paulstretch.

My thinking is that this may be possible using Automator, but I'm not really too sure how to set that up. I also know that the source code is available online, so it could be possible to redesign the interface in some sort of way. Or perhaps there is another way of doing it via terminal commands...I don't know.

Does anybody have any suggestions? If we could crack this then I'm sure that it would be a useful tool for the community. Also, if anyone has suggestions of a better place to pose this conundrum then please let me know.

Thanks

p.s. Mac version download link is here:
http://music.cornwarning.com/2011/12/07/new-paulstretch-os-x-build/

Comment: I believe the source code is located here:
http://www.paulnasca.com/open-source-projects
http://hypermammut.sourceforge.net/paulstretch/

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party but your best bet would be to use the command line version. https://github.com/paulnasca/paulstretch_python

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I don't think PS can batch file process.

Hope this helps - S

Comment: Yes, I understand that. What I'm trying to figure out is if there is a way to do batch processing using some other process like Automator or even getting into the source code. The problem is that so far I have been able to get a decent solution.